# Using structfun with a list of fields

Tags: matlab, octave

What is the right way of doing something like `structfun(@(x) foo.x, fields)`, where `fields` is a list of struct fields?

Comment: What would be the intended result? Can you give a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming fields is a cell array, something like this should work

```
y = cellfun(@(y) foo.x.(y), fields);
```